Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:buildCMakeRelWithDebInfo[arm64-v8a]'
I am trying to build release of my app which is running fine on emulator.
I've included a screenshot of my package.json file for reference.

When I initiate the app using the command ./gradlew assembleRelease, I encounter the following error

I am using windows 10.
I have tried building my release build please help.

Welcome to SO. Please provide a minimal reproducible example so others can try to reproduce the error.
Also, please do not share code or errors as images. Copy and paste these and format using markdown.
